# Execute method in a scheduled manner

Tags: java, spring

I want to execute a call to a particular method every minute, and it should get called with the server startup. This should be a single thread.

I tried using the CRON job , but am facing some issues with it.

Is there any way through which I can achieve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ExecutorServices...

```
  Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate( new Runnable()
  {

     @Override
     public void run()
     {
        // call your method here

     }
  }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES );
```

Comment: But how do I call this method on server startup and who would be calling this class.

Comment: Is the server a separate application to the code who's method you want to run every minute, or is this intended to be part of the server?

Comment: this is intended to be part of the server

Comment: You could use a batch file (or similar alternative) to start both the server and your app, and in your app use the above code.

Answer (score 2):

For a similar task i am using a Quartz scheduler. It is very easy to use. My intervals are larger than a minute though, but this should not matter. 
You have the option to specify how many threads your scheduler will be using in a config file.

http://quartz-scheduler.org/

http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/

Comment: How to configure it to load on server startup ?

Comment: @Vivek I have a servlet which is "loaded on startup". The servlet's init method creates the Property file which is used to configure the Quartz scheduler. Then i have several methods in the same servlet, that define different JobDetails and Trigger. JobDetail and Trigger are specific for the Quartz scheduler. Those methods are just jobs that are added to the schedule to be executed. Take a look at the Api and you will figure them out. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JBoss (may also apply to other AS, I have no data on them), you may want to try the bundled [**quartz scheduler**](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). It offers very finegrained job control. You don't have to use the bundled version though, and are free to use it as dependency on the AS of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring Tasks to achieve this easily using annotations.  They are in the context jars so you shouldn't have to add any new jars to achieve this.

In your appContext add (adjust the pool-size accordingly):

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="2"/>
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="2"/>
```

You'll need to pull in the appropriate namespace too:

```
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
```

After you do all of this you should be able to just annotate the method you want to be called.  Since you want your method called every minute you should use fixedRate:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=60000)
```

Doing this should force the call to run on startup and every minute thereafter.  The time as you can probably see is set in milliseconds.

Comment: So in this case , the executor and scheduler are 2 classes is it ?

Comment: They are two classes but with the base setup they will be instantiated for you automatically.  The task namespace takes care of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Execute a particular method every minute? This sounds like you need a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). Have a look at [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information. Timer executes the method at a background thread - why is it important to execute the method within your main thread?

Answer (score 0):

```
class DemoThread extends Thread {

public void run() {
   while(true) {
     try {
       sleep(60000);
     }
     catch(InterruptedException e) {
     }
     // call some random method here
   }
 }
}
```

Init the Thread and run it.

```
DemoThread thread = new DemoThread();
thread.start();
```